# Where is SignTool /d info (description of the signed content) used/displayed?

Tags: code-signing, signtool

In the [`SignTool` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe#sign) it is said:

> `/d` Specifies a description of the signed content.

Where can I find that description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One significant place, where the description is shown, is on the UAC prompt, when running a signed application (typically an installer) that needs Administrator privileges:

[image]